# cannot implicitly convert type int? to string[]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a login page that Username is the emaloyee ID which is an Integer. however to validate my loging I need to convert it to string, but it continuesly gives me same error.

I have tried all of these but sill get same error :

```
string s = i.ToString();
string s = Convert.ToString(i);
string s = int.Parse(i);

serializeModel.roles = user.RoleROLE_ID; error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string[]'
```

what I suppose to do with this one?

[image]

here is my code :

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl = "")
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int modelID = int.Parse(model.EMP_ID);
                var user = db.EMPLOYEEs.Where(u => u.EMP_ID == modelID && u.EMP_PASSWORD == model.EMP_PASSWORD).FirstOrDefault();
                    if ( user !=null)
                {
                    var roles = db.EMPLOYEEs.Select(m => m.RoleROLE_ID).ToArray();

                    CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = new CustomPrincipalSerializeModel();
                    serializeModel.UserId = user.EMP_ID;
                    serializeModel.FirstName = user.EMP_FIRST_NAME;
                    serializeModel.LastName = user.EMP_LAST_NAME;
                    serializeModel.roles = user.RoleROLE_ID;
```

Comment: you are trying to convert a single int to an array of strings, that wont work

Comment: this not suppose to be an array anymore because I have a table of roles, when an employee is being registered a role will be assigned to them. So, when they log in the information comes from employee table where the role is already being selected... so there is no array.

Comment: user.RoleROLE_ID.Value.ToString()

Comment: thank you, this did the magic : serializeModel.roles = new string[]{ user.RoleROLE_ID.toString() }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign a int? to a string array...

This should fix it.

```
serializeModel.roles = new string[]{ user.RoleROLE_ID.ToString() };
```

Comment: if it is working accept it, so that others with the same problem don't look further anymore